# Number of heads $\geq 15 \space + $ number of tails or number of tails $\geq 25 \space + $ number of heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose you have a fair coin. What is the expected number of flips that you need until you have at least $15$ more heads than tails OR you have at least $25$ more tails than heads?

Given that the coin is fair, the event in question seems very unlikely... how do we approach this?

Comment: It is worth trying with smaller numbers than $15$ and $30$:  for example with $1$ and $1$ it is obviously $1$, while with $1$ and $2$ it turns out to be $2$.  What about with $1$ and $3$ or with $2$ and $2$?  Can you spot a pattern? Van you prove it?

Comment: In general, the expected number of steps to hit one of the barriers at $a$ or $-b$ when starting at $0$ is $ab$:  one way of proving it is to set up the recursion $E_c = 1 + \frac12 E_{c-1} + \frac12 E_{c+1}$ with $E_a=E_{-b}=0$ which gives a set of linear simultaneous equations with a single solution, and $E_c = (a-c)(c+b)$ satisfies it, giving $E_0=ab$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about the simple random walk. Let $X_n$ be the number of heads minus the number of tails; $X_0=0$ and $X_{n+1}=X_n\pm1 $ with equal probability. Let
$$\tau=\min\{n: X_n=15\text{ or }X_n=-25\}.$$
You need to compute $\mathbb{E}\tau$.

Note that $\tau<\infty$ a.s., and $\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=15)=\frac{25}{15+25}=\frac58$, $\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=15)=1-\frac58=\frac38$ by the [Gambler's ruin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Solution: let $Y_n=X_n^2-n$. Then $Y_n$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration generated by $X_1,X_2,\dots$; namely $\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}-Y_n\mid X_n)=0$. By the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem),
$$
\mathbb{E} Y_{\tau}=Y_0=0
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} Y_{\tau}&=\mathbb{E} (X_\tau^2-\tau)
=15^2\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_\tau=15)+(-25)^2\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_\tau=-25)-\mathbb{E}\tau
\\ &
=15^2\cdot \frac58+(-25)^2\cdot \frac38-\mathbb{E}\tau
\end{align*}
so $\mathbb{E}\tau=375$.

Comment: More generally, the expected number of steps to hit one of the barriers at $a$ or $-b$ when starting at $0$ is $ab$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be random variables modeling the outcomes of the tosses. Define $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (1_{X_k=H}-1_{X_k=T})$$
and note that you're looking for the hitting time of the event $\{S_n\geq 15 \}\cup \{S_n\leq -25 \}$. Note also that $S_n$ is a symmetric random walk with $S_0=0$. Hence you're looking for the hitting time of a barrier for a symmetric random walk.

This is a well-known problem.

Comment: though the barriers are not symmetric